# Correct way to change a list of strings to list of ints

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
dict = {0: ['2', '6'], 1: ['2'], 2: ['3']}

print("Original: ")
print(dict)

for key,vals in dict.items():
    vals = [int(s) for s in vals]

print("New: ")
print(dict)
```

Output:

```
Original: 
{0: ['2', '6'], 1: ['2'], 2: ['3']}
New: 
{0: ['2', '6'], 1: ['2'], 2: ['3']}
```

I can't figure why the list of values is not changing, I have tried the map() function and it also does not work, any reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't overwrite actually values in your dictionary. Try to do:

```
for key,vals in dict.items():
    dict[key] = [int(s) for s in vals]
```

With dict comprehensions it looks much better, actually. I just tried to show what should be changed in your code.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3:

```
dict = {k: list(map(int, v)) for k, v in dict.items()}
```

Comment: In the first row - I suppose it for Python 2 - you have a mistake. You should change it to something like `dict(((k, list(map(int, v))) for k, v in d.items()))` because Python 2 doesn't support dict generator

Comment: I was thinking about Python 2.7 which has it backported. I remove first row entirely since tags has `python` and most recent version that all should aim to work with is Python 3.